# How can I solve not an sstable bad magic number error

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

My friend and I are making a deep learning model for image recognition for a hackathon and we keep on ecountering this issue.

Basically when I run my run.py to analyze and image it returns the sstable (bad magic number) error.

We don't know why this is happening or what to do.

Here is run.py:

```
    import os, gc
from skimage import io
import glob
import pandas as pd
import glob
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, save_model, load_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage import transform
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.applications import mobilenet_v2
from PIL import Image
path = []
for file in os.listdir("./media_cdn"):
    path.append(file)
print(path)
filepath = './saved_model'
model = load_model(filepath, custom_objects= None, compile = False)
loss = 'CategoricalCrossentropy'
optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-5)
metrics = ['binary_accuracy']
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=metrics)
def load(filename):
np_image = Image.open("./media_cdn/" + filename)
np_image = np.array(np_image).astype('float32')/255
np_image = transform.resize(np_image, (244, 244, 3))
np_image = np.expand_dims(np_image, axis=0)
return np_image
new_image = load(path[0])
print(new_image.shape)
new_model = keras.Sequential([model])
new_model.load_weights('./model_weights')
prediction = new_model.predict_classes(new_image)
classes = np.argmax(prediction, axis = -1)
print(classes)
print('This is the Diagnosis:')
if classes == 0:
    print('MELANOMA')
if classes == 1:
    print('Melanocytic Nevus')
if classes == 2:
    print('Basal Cell Carcinoma')
if classes == 3:
    print('Arctinic Keratosis')
if classes == 4:
    print('Benign Keratosis')
if classes == 5:
    print('Dermatofibroma')
if classes == 6:
    print('Vascular Lesion')
if classes == 7:
    print('Squamous Cell Carcinoma')
if classes == 8:
    print(['Unknown', 'BCC', 'AK', 'BKL', 'DF', 'VASC', 'SCC', 'UNK'])
classes = np.argmax(prediction, axis = 1)
print(classes)
```

When debugging the error is showing up in the `load_model` line.

We don't know how to fix it, and any help would be welcome.

Comment: The actual error with a stacktrace would be helpful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I figured out why this might have been happening. It seems that I had to run the model on my computer so it could generate the proper variable, and model files.